# How to properly parameterize my postgresql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to parameterize my postgresql query in order to prevent SQL injection in my ruby on rails application. The SQL query will sum a different value in my table depending on the input.

Here is a simplified version of my function:

```
def self.calculate_value(value)
    calculated_value = ""
    if value == "quantity"
        calculated_value = "COALESCE(sum(amount), 0)"
    elsif value == "retail"
        calculated_value = "COALESCE(sum(amount * price), 0)"
    elsif value == "wholesale"
        calculated_value = "COALESCE(sum(amount * cost), 0)"
    end
    
    query = <<-SQL
        select CAST(? AS DOUBLE PRECISION) as ? from table1
    SQL
    return Table1.find_by_sql([query, calculated_value, value])
end
```

If I call `calculate_value("retail")`, it will execute the query like this:

```
select location, CAST('COALESCE(sum(amount * price), 0)' AS DOUBLE PRECISION) as 'retail' from table1 group by location
```

This results in an error. I want it to execute without the quotes like this:

```
select location, CAST(COALESCE(sum(amount * price), 0) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) as retail from table1 group by location
```

I understand that the addition of quotations is what prevents the sql injection but how would I prevent it in this case? What is the best way to handle this scenario?

**EDIT:** I added an extra column to be fetched from the table to highlight that I can't use `pick` to get one value.

Comment: What is the result you're looking for? `Table1.find_by_sql` will try to make `Table1` objects, but you're feeding it a single column. Do you just want the results of the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_by_sql` is used when you want to populate objects with a single line of literal SQL. But we can use ActiveRecord for most of this, we just need one single column. To make objects, use [`select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select). If you just want results use [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck).

As you're picking from a fixed set of strings there's no risk of SQL injection in this code. Use `Arel.sql` to pass along a SQL literal you know is safe.

```
def self.calculate_value(result_name)
  sum_sql = case result_name
    when "quantity"
      "sum(amount)"
    when "retail"
      "sum(amount * price)"
    when "wholesale"
      "sum(amount * cost)"
    end

  sum_sql = Arel.sql(
    "coalesce(cast(#{sum_sql} as double precision), 0) as #{result_name}"
  )

  return Table1
    .group(:location)
    # replace pluck with select to get Table1 objects
    .pluck(:location, sum_sql)
end
```

Comment: I made an edit to the OP. In most cases, I don't want to fetch just 1 value. I just had it like that to simplify the query.

Comment: @tee Use `pluck`. Same principle applies. `Table1.group(:location).pluck(:location, Arel.sql("..."))`.

Comment: my query is oversimplified. I will want to use find_by_sql as I'm writing more complex queries.

Comment: @tee I'm sorry, you'll need to provide something representative of your problem. Usually find_by_sql can be avoided. Binding is for values, you're adding identifiers. Use quote_column_name. But since they're fixed strings they're safe and don't need quoting.